# Simple plot in python of a numpy array?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have an array that looks like this

```
cplr = array([ 0.01828922,  0.01972157,  0.02342053, ...,  0.25928021,
    0.26352547,  0.26883406])
```

If I say

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt(cplr)
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

How do I plot the contents of a numpy array?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot` is a module; the function to plot is `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`. Thus, you should do

```
plt.plot(cplr)
plt.show()
```

A good place to learn more about this would be to read a [matplotlib tutorial](https://github.com/rougier/matplotlib-tutorial).

Comment: Now I get In [66]: plt.plot(cplr)
Out[66]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1077fdad0>] and no plot appears?

Comment: You might need plt.show(block=True) depending on your matplotlib backend.